# Interface like Google Play Store

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, scroll, android-recyclerview

I am trying to achieve something similar to Google Play Store. What I need to do is have one scrollable `activity` composed by *horizontal* list of items, then a vertical list of items, then a horizontal list of items and finally another vertical list of items.

To get the data for all the four lists I will have to call four different API endpoints.

What I have right now is a host activity with 4 fragments. Each fragment is responsible of calling the API and get the list of items. Each fragment creates a `recyclerview` and uses an adapter to build the list and show it. I can successfully get the data from all the `fragments` but the activity is only showing the first fragment for some reason (also I have doubts that the activity holding 4 `recyclerviews` will be able to handle a vertical scroll).

If I set a fixed weight, it will show the 4 fragments squeezed but no scroll. But that's not what I am looking for.

**MainActivity**

```
    public class MainActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        transaction.add(R.id.first_container, FirstFragment.newInstance(parameter1));
        transaction.add(R.id.second_container, SecondFragment.newInstance(parameter2));
        transaction.add(R.id.third_container, FirstFragment.newInstance(parameter3));
        transaction.add(R.id.fourth_container, SecondFragment.newInstance(parameter4));

        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

**activity_main**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/first_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/second_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/third_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fourth_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Then all my four `fragments` have a layout with a `recyclerview` where in the code I set it up as *horizontal* or vertical depending on the `fragment`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/SwipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Any idea on how I can achieve what I am trying?

Comment: what happens if fragment layout_width is wrap_content? You shouldn't not be able to do this, but the swipe refresh on each fragment in a vertically scrolling activity worries me, that seems like something to watch

Comment: If I set layout_width to wrap_content for every fragment nothing happens. Also I am going to remove the swipe refresh.

Comment: and what if you perform one fragment transaction per fragment? (i.e., do it BeginTransaction and Commit four times)

Comment: Same result, only the first fragment shows up.

Comment: hmm, and can you confirm that all the fragments are being added? (Do something simple like verify that they are attached and have height/width above 0)

Comment: Also - you have no scrollview or nestedscrollview in your xml, that would stop the activity from scrolling - unless that's a typo (like MainActivity not extending Activity :P). One thing I normally do is start with one, then two then so on when this sort of thing happens. Verify that you can have fragment one on screen properly, then one /and/ two, etc

Comment: I manage to solve it with a few things. First added a NestedScrollView, then on every fragment I called setNestedScrollingEnabled(false). Finally I set layout_height in every fragment to wrap_content. Vertical scrolling is a bit clunky sometimes but it will do. I am just feeling that this is not the right way to do it

Comment: when you scroll and the touch event originates on one of your other scrolling objects, it will capture the scroll event for that scrollview and not the parent one, do some searching around that to make it feel less clunky

Comment: Thanks. Not sure what to mark as accepted answer as it is a combination of your tips, Kamran suggestions and my own research.

Comment: you could compile what worked for you as an answer of your own and accept it since that's the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get this working in the following way. First I wrapped the LinearLayout containing all the fragments with a NestedScrollView

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/first_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/second_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/third_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fourth_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Then on every fragment I called 
    mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

Finally I set layout_height in every fragment to wrap_content, also on the RecyclerView.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the `LinearLayout` in your `activity_main.xml` with a `ScrollView` like:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/first_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/second_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/third_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fourth_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**Note:** Remember to change the height of your `LinearLayout` to `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [click this link](https://github.com/sajadshokri/Core-Adapter)  recyclerView adapter (Core-adapter) for handling multiple type of views.Just read the tutorial and see the sample code, you can find your correct answer.